# error when installing module Text::Unaccent

Tags: windows, perl, cpan, strawberry-perl

trying to install the `Text::Unaccent` module

I have next error, Can someone help ?

```
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
   Unaccent.o:Unaccent.c:(.text+0x96):
      undefined reference to `unac_debug_callback'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake: *** [Makefile:480: blib\arch\auto\Text\Unaccent\Unaccent.xs.dll] Error 1
  LDACHARY/Text-Unaccent-1.08.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\gmake.exe -- NOT OK
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'Text::Unaccent'.
```

[Wrapped long lone for readability]

Comment: *"undefined reference to `unac_debug_callback`"*: I think this was reported 4 years ago here: https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=124815

Comment: The workaround provided in the bug report didn't works. I open a ticket.

Comment: Ok, I will check it later.

Comment: The workaround worked for me on Windows 11, see answer below

Answer (score 4):

> undefined reference to unac_debug_callback

This issue has been reported earlier here:
https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=124815

As commented by SREZIC in that thread: Adding

```
 #define HAS_VPRINTF
```

to `unac.c` seems to workaround the problem. I tested this on Windows 11, Strawberry perl version 5.32.1 and this works fine:

- Downloaded the tar ball here: https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/L/LD/LDACHARY/Text-Unaccent-1.08.tar.gz
- Unpacked and extracted the tar ball
- Cd into the unpacked directory, and edit `unac.c`. Like the following patch shows:

  ```
  diff --git a/unac.c b/unac.c
  index 20863d2..2c63fc2 100644
  --- a/unac.c
  +++ b/unac.c
  @@ -20,6 +20,7 @@
   #include "config.h"
   #endif /* HAVE_CONFIG_H */

  +#define HAS_VPRINTF
   /*
    * Perl config.h defines HAS_VPRINTF if printf variants are
    * available
  ```
- Run `perl Makefile.PL; gmake; gmake test; gmake install`:

:

```
>perl Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good

Generating a gmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Text::Unaccent
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json

>gmake
cp Unaccent.pm blib\lib\Text\Unaccent.pm
Running Mkbootstrap for Unaccent ()
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" -MExtUtils::Command -e chmod -- 644 "Unaccent.bs"
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e cp_nonempty -- Unaccent.bs blib\arch\auto\Text\Unaccent\Unaccent.bs 644
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" "C:\Strawberry\perl\lib\ExtUtils/xsubpp"  -typemap C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\ExtUtils\typemap  Unaccent.xs > Unaccent.xsc
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" -MExtUtils::Command -e mv -- Unaccent.xsc Unaccent.c
gcc -c  -I. -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -s -O2   -DVERSION=\"1.08\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.08\"  "-IC:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE"  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H Unaccent.c
Unaccent.xs: In function 'XS_Text__Unaccent_unac_string':
Unaccent.xs:71:20: warning: passing argument 5 of 'unac_string' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
           &buffer, &buffer_length) == 0) {
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from Unaccent.xs:35:
unac.h:96:23: note: expected 'size_t *' {aka 'long long unsigned int *'} but argument is of type 'int *'
   char** out, size_t* out_length);
               ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
Unaccent.xs: In function 'XS_Text__Unaccent_unac_string_utf16':
Unaccent.xs:88:19: warning: passing argument 4 of 'unac_string_utf16' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
          &buffer, &buffer_length) == 0) {
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from Unaccent.xs:35:
unac.h:79:23: note: expected 'size_t *' {aka 'long long unsigned int *'} but argument is of type 'int *'
   char** out, size_t* out_length);
               ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
Unaccent.xs: In function 'XS_Text__Unaccent_unac_debug':
Unaccent.xs:109:10: warning: implicit declaration of function 'unac_debug_callback'; did you mean 'unac_debug_print'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
          unac_debug_callback(in, unac_debug_print, NULL);
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          unac_debug_print
gcc -c  -I. -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -s -O2   -DVERSION=\"1.08\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.08\"  "-IC:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE"  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H unac.c
unac.c: In function 'unac_string':
unac.c:13889:59: warning: passing argument 6 of 'convert' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     if(convert(charset, utf16be(), in, in_length, &utf16, &utf16_length) < 0) {
                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
unac.c:13774:27: note: expected 'size_t *' {aka 'long long unsigned int *'} but argument is of type 'int *'
      char** outp, size_t* out_lengthp)
                   ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
unac.c:13893:63: warning: passing argument 4 of 'unac_string_utf16' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     unac_string_utf16(utf16, utf16_length, &utf16_unaccented, &utf16_unaccented_length);
                                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
unac.c:13674:30: note: expected 'size_t *' {aka 'long long unsigned int *'} but argument is of type 'int *'
         char** outp, size_t* out_lengthp)
                      ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" -MExtUtils::Mksymlists \
     -e "Mksymlists('NAME'=>\"Text::Unaccent\", 'DLBASE' => 'Unaccent', 'DL_FUNCS' => {  }, 'FUNCLIST' => [], 'IMPORTS' => {  }, 'DL_VARS' => []);"
g++ Unaccent.def -o blib\arch\auto\Text\Unaccent\Unaccent.xs.dll -mdll -s -L"C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE" -L"C:\STRAWB~1\c\lib" Unaccent.o unac.o   "C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\libperl532.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\lib\libiconv.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libmoldname.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libkernel32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libuser32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libgdi32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libwinspool.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libcomdlg32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libadvapi32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libshell32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libole32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\liboleaut32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libnetapi32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libuuid.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libws2_32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libmpr.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libwinmm.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libversion.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libodbc32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libodbccp32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libcomctl32.a" -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" -MExtUtils::Command -e chmod -- 755 blib\arch\auto\Text\Unaccent\Unaccent.xs.dll

>gmake test
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e cp_nonempty -- Unaccent.bs blib\arch\auto\Text\Unaccent\Unaccent.bs 644
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib\lib', 'blib\arch')" t/*.t
t/unac.t .. ok
All tests successful.
Files=1, Tests=4,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.00 usr +  0.00 sys =  0.00 CPU)
Result: PASS

> gmake install
[...]
Files found in blib\arch: installing files in blib\lib into architecture dependent library tree
Installing C:\STRAWB~1\perl\site\lib\auto\Text\Unaccent\Unaccent.xs.dll
Installing C:\STRAWB~1\perl\site\lib\Text\Unaccent.pm
Appending installation info to C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib/perllocal.pod
```